# Ionic Framework Build for IOS on El Capitan - Build Error (GCC?)

Tags: android, ios, macos, gcc, ionic-framework

So I have an app...  Android builds just fine.  Xcode is installed and updated (and opens the proj, but isn't working properly like Android). Brew updated.  GCC 4.9 installed and updated. GCC 5.x installed and updated.

**UPDATE:**

- Cordova Version: 5.3.3
- Ionic Version: 1.7.5
- Xcode Version: 7.0.1

When I run `ionic run ios` or `ionic build ios`, I get the following:

```
$ ionic build ios
Running command:     /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>
add to body class: platform-ios
Running command: /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/cordova/build 
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator9.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = i386

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

ProcessPCH /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/estore/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/estore/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/estore/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Android-SDK/tools:/Applications/Android-SDK/tools:/Applications/Android-SDK/tools"
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/emulator/include -I/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CordovaLib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/emulator -DDEBUG -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch -o /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.dia
gcc-4.9: error: /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.dia: No such file or directory
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fmacro-backtrace-limit=0'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fobjc-arc'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fpascal-strings'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicate-method-match'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wconstant-conversion'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wint-conversion'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wbool-conversion'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wenum-conversion'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fasm-blocks'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-mios-simulator-version-min=6.0'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-fobjc-legacy-dispatch'
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '--serialize-diagnostics'
Command /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-dfsftoblrnqbbfbitbtcmqjdikqe/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch CordovaLib_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/<my app>/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

I'm stuck and I need to get this to build...   Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.  It was a permissions error.  Running under `sudo` fixed it initially, and then when I cleaned the perms on the rest of the folders, it worked fine without `sudo`.